# How to fix this error with the return type in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, location

A null safety error is shown in the dart file. How to fix this?

[image]

[UPDATE]

After I made any of the suggested changes below. I get this error. How do I fix this?
[image: Exception caught by widgets library]

[image: Error shown in emulator]

Comment: try putting a ? before or after the **getPlaces**

Comment: You can't return null if the position is null. You might have to create a dummy future which contains a List of places that's empty.

Comment: Please share any relevant code [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) by editing your Question. Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.

Answer (score 1):

An additional question mark '?' along with a data type means that the value to be returned or to be assigned can be either of data type or null as well. For example, if its `int a;`, then 'a' can only take integers value and 'null' wont be allowed at any cost. `int? a;` will let 'a' hold 'null' value along with integers.

Thus, In your update function of ProxyProvider2, since there might be a chance of returning null as the value (as per the ternary condition), thus, you must mention so by replacing `Future<List<Place>>` (no null value allowed) with `Future<List<Place>>?` (null value allowed).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on your return condition you have a case that you return `null` while your closure is `Future<List<Place>>` which doesn't support this. Try changing the closure to `Future<List<Place>>?` but I don't know how this will effect the rest of your code.

Instead of `null` you can try returning an empty array `Future.value([])`.

Comment: Then I'm getting this error `The following assertion was thrown building _InheritedProviderScope<Future<List<Place>>?>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<Position?>, _InheritedProviderScope<BitmapDescriptor?>], value: null):
Tried to listen to an InheritedWidget in a life-cycle that will never be called again.
`

Answer (score 0):

A ghetto fix to this problem would to just return a future with an empty list if there's no position given.

return this instead of the null you're returning.

```
Future.value(List<int>.empty())
```

In a more proper fix, you should change the required type to `Future<List<Place>>?` so that you can return the `null`.